# How watch all files on web server?

Tags: php, file, webserver

I want to watch all files on web server dirrectory (examle: yap.com and all directories on this server ). How i can do it on PHP. If you can, please take me a complete file. Becouse i am lamer on PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not read remote server directory.

Answer (score 0):

i think u can use

http://phpfm.sourceforge.net/

and the rest is u should read documentation

Comment: try it by yourself to get directories and files from google.com (or any other website).